# Reuse ASP.NET MVC 5 code to build RESTfull Web Api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-web-api2

**Cenario**

Website: ASP.Net MVC 5 managing models, controllers and views.

Api: RESTful Web api managing models, controllers and returning JSON

**The problem:** Code duplication in BL. We are always redoing the same logic in both places.

**The approach I have in mind:**

- Take the BL out of the Website MVC and keep it only in Web Api in a separated VS solution
- The Website now is a consumer of Web Api
- About the content negotiation, I think in two options:

  1. Web Api "knows" which format to return (ViewResult, JSON or XML) and serialize/deserialize in BL depending of who is requesting (website, mobile apps, etc.). The advantage I see is to keep taking 
     advantage of strongly typed model to render a view in Website
  2. Web Api always return JSON and the consumer app handle result in client

**Questions:**

1. Is this approach a good practise?
2. Which is better: Web Api always returning JSON or a smart Web Api who "knows" which format to return?

Comment: the website should handle what the API gives it - DO NOT have the api send a different response based on who requested it

Comment: Why is the web application going to consume the web service?  Are they not running in the same context?  If they truly need to be separate applications then either create additional services for the web application to use or have it consume the services which already exist.

Comment: David, they are already two different applications. The website has controllers returing Viewresult and it is good to render Views because it is strong typed. The other application is Web Api implementing RESTfull CRUD operations (the same of controllers in website) returning only JSON. So I want to reuse Web Api but negotiating returning content.

Comment: Scott, why not? I would like a request called from website to return ViewResult and a request called from any other app return JSON/XML. I don´t want code same business logic in both controller and Web Api.

Comment: TIP: With the new Web API controllers, you can control the returned format with the "ACCEPT" header.  [Accept = application/json] = JSON, [Accept = application/xml] = XML, [Accept = text\html] = HTML, etc... this way the caller "knows what it wants" and the Web API just serves up what is requested.

Answer (score 1):

Like @David said, you don't really need to consume web services in your MVC controllers. You could just design it in such a way that your MVC and API layers are just another "view" to your Business layer. So, in case you are thinking in a terms of your visual studio solution, your might have a Data layer project, a Business layer project and 2 front end projects MVC and API.

Comment: This is one scenario where the "don't put business logic in your views and controllers" is extremely important.  If all of your logic is kept in a lower level component (Biz Layer, Data Layer, etc...) then the Web API becomes the Raw Data view, and the MVC controllers are just views of the same data wrapped in a friendly user interface.

Comment: Sunil, you are saying that I can build a Class Library BL instead of Web Api BL? If I understand correctly, the BL is responsible for content negotiation and both MVC and API use the same BL?

Comment: BL is a simple class library with business logic. Lets say in the BL you have a class called `ProductBL` and method called `GetProducts()` which returns `IList<Product>()`. In the MVC controller you will instantiate the `var productBL = new ProductBL()` and then call `var listOfProducts = productBL.GetProducts()`. Now, you have listOfProducts which you can send to your view. Now, in the web api controller you will do exactly the same and just return listOfProducts to the caller as json or whatever your caller wants.